# How to make carousel responsive?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, frontend, carousel

I am using below code to make carousel having vertical images. It is not responsive i.e. it works completely fine on desktop but on reducing screen size, images are not fully visible (i.e half portion of image is not visible in carousel).

How can I remove this bug?

```
<div class="container ">
   <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-11 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
      <div id="carousel-pager" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
         <div class="carousel-inner vertical">
            <div class="active item" style="object-fit: fill;">
               <img  style="object-fit: fill;" src="..." class="img-responsive" data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="0" width:100>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="object-fit: fill;">
               <img src="..." class="img-responsive" data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="1">
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="object-fit: fill;">
               <img src="..." class="img-responsive" data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="2">
            </div>
         </div>
         <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-pager" role="button" data-slide="prev">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
         </a>
         <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-pager" role="button" data-slide="next">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using bootstrap, you should add the classes: `d-block` and `mx-auto` for responsiveness to all the img tags.

like so:

```
<img src="..." class="d-block mx-auto" data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="2">
```

It will make them responsive.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

also change all the div `class="item"` to  `div class="carousel-item"`

OR use this:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Michael I tried this, didn't work. Still image is half visible.

Comment: your errors are with the classes, you should stick to bootstrap classes, add yours but don't change the others. add this to the div classess class="carousel-item",

Comment: "carousel-item" makes verticle slider to horizontal I didn’t  add it but thanks  just adding d-block w-100 class worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

I have added `min-width: 100%;` to make image take full container.

Comment: Hi @kevin, I added this but no change. still issue is same.

Comment: @someonetonobody Where you added?

Comment: I am adding in vue.js css(scoped) gave img a class and added css.
"to make image take full container."--this is something I dont need in webapp.

Comment: @someonetonobody When Image take full container it won't cut half portion. You may add them to your custom stylesheet and link to HTML.